# List of IP addresses found on the network

Tags: c#, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I've been working on a project for a while now where I need to create a list of IP addresses and then see if they respond to a specific command string.
the process goes something like this:

- choose a NIC to scan with
- Start a basic packet capture that only looks for Ip addresses and ports
- create a list (Named: IP List) containing all of the addresses found on the network within the current subnet
- create a second list (Named:  host info)
- loop through the IP List and determine two things

  - If the host has been added to the host info list.
  - if the host has been added move to the next IP address
  - If the app needs to communicate with it, and notate appropriate attributes

I've tried to eliminate duplicates in the IP List but for some reason (probably a threading thing???) there are always a few ip addresses that get listed several times.

Here is a code snippet of what happens when a packet arrives:

```
public  void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, PacketCapture e)
    {
        
       var time = e.Header.Timeval.Date;
        var len = e.Data.Length;
        var rawPacket = e.GetPacket();
        var packet = PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket(rawPacket.LinkLayerType, rawPacket.Data);

        var tcpPacket = packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.TcpPacket>();
        if (tcpPacket != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("<-------------------TCP--------------------->");
            var ipPacket = (PacketDotNet.IPPacket)tcpPacket.ParentPacket;
            System.Net.IPAddress srcIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress;
            System.Net.IPAddress dstIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress;
            int srcPort = tcpPacket.SourcePort;
            int dstPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2},{3} Len={4} {5}:{6} -> {7}:{8}",
                time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second, time.Millisecond, len,
                srcIp, srcPort, dstIp, dstPort);

            if (device_ips.Contains(srcIp.ToString())) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the list contains the current ip");
                //dataGridView1.Refresh();
                //label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();

                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate

                    {
                        dataGridView1.Refresh();
                        label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
                    }));


                }
                else
                {
                    //label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
                }



            }
            else
            {
                string ipinquestion = srcIp.ToString();
                device_ips.Add(ipinquestion);
                MyProperty++;
                
               
            }
            if (device_ips.Contains(dstIp.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the list contains the current ip");
                //dataGridView1.Refresh();
                //label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();


                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate

                    {
                        dataGridView1.Refresh();
                        label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Stuff & Junk");
                    }));


                }
                else
                {
                    //label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string ipinquestion = dstIp.ToString();
                device_ips.Add(ipinquestion);
                MyProperty++;


            }

        }

        var udpPacket = packet.Extract<PacketDotNet.UdpPacket>();
        if(udpPacket != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("<-------------------UDP--------------------->");
            var uipPacket = (PacketDotNet.IPPacket)udpPacket.ParentPacket;
            System.Net.IPAddress sourceIP = uipPacket.SourceAddress;
            System.Net.IPAddress destinationIP = uipPacket.DestinationAddress;
            int usrcPort = udpPacket.SourcePort;
            int udestPort = udpPacket.DestinationPort;
            string myipaddress = sourceIP.ToString();
            if (device_ips.Contains(myipaddress))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the list contains the current ip");
            }else
            {
                string ipinquestion = sourceIP.ToString();
                device_ips.Add(ipinquestion);

                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate

                    {
                        foreach (var i in device_ips)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                        }
                    }));


                }
                else
                {
                    //label2.Text = MyProperty.ToString();
                }



                

                MyProperty++;

            }

            
        }

    }
```

How can I reduce the potential for duplicate IP addresses from getting by the "if (device_ips.Contains(srcIp.ToString())) " line?

Comment: Use a `HashSet<string>` not a `List<string>` to store IPs so that you can only add unique items? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You could also consider discovering IP addresses on the local network segment via ARP requests.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I'll definitely give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman in this app hosts may be added after the app has started.  I assume that the ARP request is a one time event and wouldn't necessarily "catch" new ip addresses appearing on the network after the ARP request is made correct?